# Media_Unavailable MediaException - But file is in the same folder as classes

Tags: java, audio, io, embedded-resource

## The Rundown

- I want to add some flair to my program.
- I wanted to add some background music.
- I tried following googled solutions, but nothing I tried worked.
- My music is a '.wav' file.
- My file is in the same folder as my project.

### My Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;



public class musicPlayer extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        String path = "bkgmsc.wav";
        Media hit = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        (new musicPlayer()).start();

    }

}
```

### Where I Use 'musicPlayer':

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        musicPlayer player = new musicPlayer();
        player.start();
}
```

## Error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE :
at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:407)
at simplesubbattlsehip.musicPlayer.run(musicPlayer.java:19)
```

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. **Note that the *correct* way to form the URL is shown at the link to the info. page.**

Comment: Thanks! Now that I think about it, it seems obvious.